# How to make Jenkins Build Parameters Sticky? (Retain last choice for next run)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

**Problem**

We want some jobs to start with defaults and modify job.  E.g., A deploy into a test environment should default to the last settings.  At present, we can configure the job prior to running.  This is OK but cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define props in the job manually or programmatically via properties.  If we do this programmatically, then we can update them once they have been selected.  The first call sets the properties for the build and the 2nd changes it to user selection.  In theory, if you set these manually, you'd only need the 2nd call

```groovy
    def stickyprops(def sticky = "initial value") {
            def propertiesAllBranches = [
                disableConcurrentBuilds(),
                [$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [
                        [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: sticky, description: '', name: 'STICKY_PARAM']]
                ]
            ]
            properties(propertiesAllBranches)
    }

    node() {
            // set to default
            stickyprops()

            // Report current user choice
            currentBuild.description = "param ${params.STICKY_PARAM}"

            // Set params to user choice
            stickyprops(params.STICKY_PARAM)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This defines a build parameter with an initial value so the first time you run the build, this initial value will be used. When another build with a different value (e.g. "new value") is triggered ("Build with Parameters"), this "new value" will be used by default.

```
parameters {
  string name: 'STICKY', defaultValue: params.STICKY?:'initial value'
}
```

I don't understand your exact use case but this answers the question "How to make Jenkins Build Parameters Sticky? (Retain last choice for next run)" for me.

Comment: You can add more details about how this can help please.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.